# Issue with django DB connectivity on heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am new to django and might be missing something obvious.

I intend to create a simple project and deploy on heroku.
Since sqlite3 is not supported on heroku, I have setup a postgres instance on elephantsql.
I have changed the settings.py file and able to connect to the postgres instance from http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "dummy",
        "USER": "dummy",
        "PASSWORD": "dummy",
        "HOST": "dummy",
        "PORT": "5432"
    }
}
```

However, I am still not able to connect from heroku.

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "home_signup" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e_signup"."email", "home_signup"."timestamp" FROM "home_sign...
                                                             ^
```

I have gone through the postgres db which heroku offers, but the free version is limited to 10rows only.So, thought of using elephantsql which has better free offering.

Any pointer will be great help.

---

Some more details:

I created an instance in elephantsql > ran the migrations locally > checked using pgAdmin4 tool > table is created

The project just takes in text from an input field and adds to a col in the table.It is able to insert records without any issues locally.I am using pgadmin to check if the record is inserted or not.

I am not doing any select or any other db operation.

Comment: Did you run a migration yet?  What did you do to create the table(s)?

Comment: Yes - I have run the migrations. I have cross checked using pgAdmin4 tool as well - all the tables are created.I am able to insert records into the tables by running the django project locally.

Comment: what do the migrations look like?  I suspect that you might be creating tables in one schema, but `SELECT`ing from another schema -- maybe look into how your `search_path` is set?

Comment: @richyen Thanks for the response. I have updated the question to add the details. Please have a check.

Answer (score 0):

Use django-heroku.

I used this video to deploy my app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DI_7Zja8Zc

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.
Heroku doesn't honor the database details as provided in settings.py

Heroku has a section called settings under its dashboard.
Under the **config vars** section, we need to add the DB TNS as a key value pair - with key=DATABASE_URL and value=DB TNS.

Screenshot:
[image]

Note: If you have a heroku provisioned postgre DB, the DATABASE_URL will point to the heroku postgre and we can't edit the value. We need to remove the postgre DB add-on first.